# Why does ifeq work differently when placed in different places?

Tags: makefile

I'm still learning how to use makefiles in windows and I'm confused with `ifeq`. What I'm trying to do is when I enter `make Z=1` in my command line, it will compile my files with `-std=c++17`.

Here's the part of the code that confuses me:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

COMMONRECIPE = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@ && @echo recompiled: $?

ifeq "$Z" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
endif
```

it works completely as expected with no issues.
However, when I change the order of the code and put the `COMMONRECIPE` variable below the code like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

ifeq "$Z" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
endif

COMMONRECIPE = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@ && @echo recompiled: $?
```

it no longer adds the `-std=c++17` flag when I do `make Z=1` as if the `ifeq` was never even there.

Here's the full code in the makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
.PHONY: default clean 

COMMONRECIPE = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@ && @echo recompiled: $?

ifeq "$Z" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
endif
ifeq "$(2A)" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -std=c++2a
endif
ifeq "$W" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -mwindows
endif
ifeq "$C" "1"
    CXXFLAGS += -mconsole
endif

default: test1.exe test2.exe test3.exe

test1.exe test1: test1.cpp
    $(COMMONRECIPE)

test2.exe test2: test2.cpp
    $(COMMONRECIPE)

test3.exe test3: test3.cpp
    $(COMMONRECIPE)

clean:
    del *.exe
```

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with [tag:c++]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Sorry I thought it did because it compiles with g++

Comment: There must be something else different about your makefile or environment because I cannot reproduce this behavior at all given these makefiles.  When run with `Z=1` I always see the `-std=c++17` option on the link line.  Just as an aside, you should definitely not use `$?` as an automatic variable because it only expands to _modified_ files, but you want to link _all_ files into your program.  You should use `$^` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see the problem.  Your first example was too cut-down: you omitted the `.PHONY` which is what's causing the problem.

The root of the issue is that you're indenting your variable assignments with TAB characters.  TABs are special to make and should *only* be used to indent recipe lines, never any makefile assignments.

By having this:

```
.PHONY: default clean 

ifeq "$Z" "1"
        CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
endif
```

where the `CXXFLAGS` assignment is indented with a TAB, you are actually putting the assignment of the variable in a recipe for the `.PHONY` target, as if you'd written this:

```
.PHONY: default clean 
        CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
```

Remember that blank lines, comment lines, and conditional statements like `ifeq` don't stop a recipe.  Only a non-recipe line stops a recipe.

Although `.PHONY` is a pseudo target and its recipe never is run, it's still a target and you can still create a recipe for it.

Change all your makefile variable assignments to be indented with spaces, not TABs, and you'll have no problems.

Comment: Probably GNU make should generate a warning if it sees someone add a recipe to `.PHONY`.